# How to replace array string type column value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have employee_df which has column ID. How do we replace the values 10000 and 30000 to 11111 and 33333 respectively using pandas.

`employee_df.head()`

```
|     id    |
| --------- |
| ["10000"] |
| ["20000"] |
| ["50000"] |
| ["30000"] |
| ["90000"] |
```

Expected output:

```
|     id    |
| --------- |
| ["11111"] |
| ["20000"] |
| ["50000"] |
| ["33333"] |
| ["90000"] |
```

I tried

```
new_df = employee_df.replace(  {"id": {   '10000':'11111',   '30000':'33333'  }} )
```

I didn't get any error, but I am not able to see the changes.

Comment: That representation suggests that you have a list object in the `id` column. You should show the output of `employee_df.head()`

Comment: What is the expected output? The replacement fails because the value inside `id` is list and not string

Comment: yes. I tried changing it, but no success. The column id has type 'pandas.core.series.Series'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Firstly remove [] and ' with regex.

```
import regex
employee_df['id'] = employee_df['id'].str.replace("[", '', regex=True)
employee_df['id'] = employee_df['id'].str.replace("]", '', regex=True)
employee_df['id'] = employee_df['id'].str.replace("'", '', regex=True)
```

Then,

```
employee_df.loc[employee_df['id'] == '10000', 'id'] = '11111'
employee_df.loc[employee_df['id'] == '30000', 'id'] = '33333'
```

Comment: I tried this and I didn't get any error, but I am not able to see the changes.

Comment: Could you please share full code actually I'm using this code in my dataframe and I get changes. I couldn't understand why you don't.

Comment: These are lists you could convert this string ( with .join function) and apply code again.